# Google Maps rendering in Internet Explorer shows grey box

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, google-maps

Im working on a simple map that shows a few markers. The code seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox, but wont render in IE. Here is a pic of what I get, when running the code: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/iemapgrey.png/

There is no javascript error, at least not in IE debug console. Here is the code:

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key={{=GOOGLEMAP_KEY}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-34.885931,-66.093750), 1);
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+5);
    map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
    // Create a base icon for all of our markers that specifies the
    // shadow, icon dimensions, etc.
    var baseIcon = new GIcon();
    baseIcon.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
    baseIcon.iconSize = new GSize(20, 34);
    baseIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
    baseIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9, 34);
    baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9, 2);
    baseIcon.infoShadowAnchor = new GPoint(18, 14);
    var blueIcon = new GIcon();
    blueIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";
    blueIcon.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
    blueIcon.iconSize = new GSize(37, 34);
    blueIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
    blueIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9, 34);
    blueIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9, 2);
    blueIcon.infoShadowAnchor = new GPoint(18, 14);

    function createMarker(point, i, message) {
       // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
       if(i==0) markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };
       else markerOptions= {}
       var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
       GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
         marker.openInfoWindowHtml(message);
       });
       return marker;
    }
    {{for row in sites:}}{{if row.latitude and row.longitude:}}
      var point = new GLatLng({{=row.latitude}},{{=row.longitude}});
      map.addOverlay(createMarker(point, 0, 'Direccion: {{=row.adress}}, Operador: {{=row.owner}} <br> <a href="site/{{=row.legacy_site_id}}">Ver Sitio</a>'));
    {{pass}}{{pass}}
 }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You are using the Google Maps API v2 which was deprecated May 2010.  You should be using the Google Maps API v3 for new maps, as v2 may be retired anytime after May 2013.

Comment: are you running this on your local machine, or on a publically available server?  Google requires the ability to talk back to your server, so if you are on your local/development machine, the map won't work correctly.  Look into using openlayers instead if this is a deal breaker.

Comment: The Google Maps API v2 works perfectly fine on a local machine.  Local development is allowed and does not even require a valid key.  Something else is wrong. The code provided doesn't look like straight javascript (`var point = new GLatLng({{=row.latitude}},{{=row.longitude}});`).

Comment: It's running in a local machine, but that isn't a problem, local development is allowed. I'm generating latitude and longitude values dynamically using python, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Anyone got a solution?